# Tabwidget on bottom side and some Edittext make stupied Effect (Tabs are shown over virtual keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, virtual, tabwidget

Do anyone know how to prevent the following Effect?
I use a Tabwidget and multiple Activities per Tab. So far so good.
Sometimes (and not always and from time to time different) my tabs are visible when i enter an Edittext View. (The Tabs are showing over the virtual keyboard, So there ich not much space to see)

The Tabs are bottom based oriented. 
My Testdevice Android 2.2 / THC